# How do I style nested flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a navbar using two flex box nested in one parent container. but I can't style inner flexbox without affecting the main container items.
my layout suppose to look like this
[navbar-idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CImG.png)

My code:

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before,
* li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.main-navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 4rem;
}

.link-container {
  display: flex;
}

.user-feature {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-navbar">
    <div class="div-1 link-container">
        <ul class="link-container">
            <li><a>HOME</a></li>
            <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a>ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://www.theodinproject.com/assets/icons/odin-icon-b5b31c073f7417a257003166c98cc23743654715305910c068b93a3bf4d3065d.svg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="div-2">
        <ul class="user-feature feature-container">
            <li><a>LOG IN</a></li>
            <li><a>CART</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

right now everything is fine but when I apply padding to link-container it also affects main-navbar items and I can't align logo verticaly center.
is it possible with flex?

I wanna know what causes flex to behave like this?

Comment: can you share a SS of what exactly you want to do with the logo?

Comment: I don't understand your code because you are applying no styling to main but you have in your CSS a navbar class setting which is never used. Could you remove any redundant CSS? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
*,
*::after,
*::before,
* li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.main-navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 4rem;
}

.link-container {
  display: flex;
 padding: 10px;
}
.image-container {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.user-feature {
  display: flex;
}
```

Give same padding*2 for padding-right of .image-container for example i gave 10px for link-container and 20px for .image-container padding-right.Thanks

Comment: What about mobile responsive? It's not a good idea for responsive design.  @hazrat Gafulov

Comment: of course this is not for mobile devices because you will not need to flex-direction row.thanks

Comment: Great, BEST OF LUCK @HazratGafulov

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do. I've just used `position:` property of **CSS**.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.main-navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin:30px 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px 4rem;
  position:relative;
}

.link-container {
  display: flex;

}
.link-container li{
  padding:10px;
}

.image-container{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%);
  
}


.user-feature {
  display: flex;
}

.user-feature li{
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
    <nav class="main-navbar">
        <div class="div-1 link-container">
            <ul class="link-container">
                <li><a>HOME</a></li>
                <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a>ABOUT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="https://www.theodinproject.com/assets/icons/odin-icon-b5b31c073f7417a257003166c98cc23743654715305910c068b93a3bf4d3065d.svg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="div-2">
            <ul class="user-feature feature-container">
                <li><a>LOG IN</a></li>
                <li><a>CART</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```